# Starting SharePoint in the browser

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, internet-explorer, windows-server

I'm new to SharePoint.
I installed [SharePoint Foundation 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35488) on Windows Server 2012 (virtual machine). After the installation, Internet Explorer started and this message came up:

[image]

It is connecting to WIN-SC193HRUATI, but I don't know what user details to enter below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the credentials of the account you used to install SharePoint in the first place (then you can grant permissions to other accounts).

If you are unsuccessful in logging in with correct credentials on the server you may need to disable loopback check: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_foxhole/archive/2010/06/21/disableloopbackcheck-lets-do-it-the-right-way.aspx

Comment: I just can't remember my credentials. I even don't know anymore, when exactly I had to define them. I just removed my SharedPoint and installed it again, but during installation it didn't ask me to define any new credentials. So I assume there are stored somewhere permanently. Any idea how to change them? (This is my own SharePoint, so nothing illegal involved here).

Comment: It is the AD account you use when you start the installation, it is not an account you create when installing SharePoint